# SSIS expression today date

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Got a flat file with some missing date values, need to turn them into todays date.

How can I do that using SSIS expressions?

*Note: (All missing date values for Orderdate column = todays date)*

Comment: This question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Dataflow task` that read from a flat file and copy rows to a destination flat file. And use a [Derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation) with the following expression

```
GETDATE()
```

*"GETDATE() Returns the current date of the system in a DT_DBTIMESTAMP format. The GETDATE function takes no arguments." [Read more about GETDATE() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/getdate-ssis-expression)*

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived column transformation. In the Transformation editor the "Derived Column" to `Replace 'MyColumn'` and use the [REPLACENULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replacenull-ssis-expression) expression.

Example: `REPLACENULL(MyColumn, GETDATE())`.